# conflict in orientation while using custom alert

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview

In my app i have created one custom alert view with one progress bar and one button , while rotate the device , custom alertview also rotate but the alert view size in automatically changed. how can i fix it? !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rotating your device, on each view a property is checked, if autoresizing for a view is enabled.

Your custom alert view, as it is certainly a subclass of UIView, has a property called `autoresizingMask`. Set the value to `UIViewAutoresizingNone` like so:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

try this for Autosizing view same like given screen shot

Comment: For the interface builder, that's what you want, yeah :-)

Comment: In interface builder see Auto sizing All are unselected.and after try this